# Como agregar un día a valor capturado de fecha de datepicker jquery ui?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-datepicker

Hola feliz año nuevo a todos. Tengo una duda, como puedo sumarle un día a valor capturado de datepicker, por ejemplo selecciono 01/12/2016, necesito sumarle un día, para que me muestre  02/12/2016.

El código que tengo es el siguiente.

var fechamin = $("#fecha1").val()

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación de jQuery UI para el datepicker, puedes encontrar los métodos [`getDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) y [`setDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) para leer y escribir la fecha respectivamente.

Una solución sería leer la fecha de un campo con `getDate`, sumarle 1 (un día) y reescribirla con el `setDate`, para después asignarle ese valor al segundo campo. Algo como esto:

```
// leemos la fecha del primer campo
var fecha = $("#fechamin").datepicker("getDate");

// la actualizamos añadiéndole un día
fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1); 

// sobreescribimos la fecha del segundo campo
$("#fechamax").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
```

Y aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
$( function() {
  $("#fechamin").datepicker();
  $("#fechamax").datepicker();

  $("#fechamin").on("change", function() {
    var fecha = $("#fechamin").datepicker("getDate");
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1); 
    $("#fechamax").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="text" id="fechamin" />
<input type="text" id="fechamax" />
```

Comment: Alvaro Montoro muchas gracias, había realizado otra solución, pero es mas tediosa en código usando moment.js, implementare la solución que tu me planteas son menos lineas de código.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una funcion que he sacado de [este post](https://reviblog.net/2014/07/01/sumar-dias-a-una-fecha-en-javascript/)

```
sumaFecha = function(d, fecha)
{
  var Fecha = new Date();
  var sFecha = fecha || (Fecha.getDate() + "/" + (Fecha.getMonth() +1) + "/" + Fecha.getFullYear());
  var sep = sFecha.indexOf('/') != -1 ? '/' : '-'; 
  var aFecha = sFecha.split(sep);
  var fecha = aFecha[2]+'/'+aFecha[1]+'/'+aFecha[0];
  fecha= new Date(fecha);
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate()+parseInt(d));
  var anno=fecha.getFullYear();
  var mes= fecha.getMonth()+1;
  var dia= fecha.getDate();
  mes = (mes < 10) ? ("0" + mes) : mes;
  dia = (dia < 10) ? ("0" + dia) : dia;
  var fechaFinal = dia+sep+mes+sep+anno;
  return (fechaFinal);
}
```

Y ejecutarlo así

```
var fechamin = $("#fecha1").val()
var fechaSumada = sumaFecha(1,fechamin); /* Le sumas un dia */
alert(fechaSumada)
```